# javascript merge two functions to check the node type with another element

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, d3.js

Given the below json structure:

```
{
    "nodes": [
        {
        "type": "school",
        "country": "US",
        "name": "saint peter's",
        "id": 1006
        },
        {
        "type": "univeristy",
        "country": "Brazil",
        "name": "saint joseph's",
        "id": 1007
        }        
        ...
    ],
    "links": [
            {
            "source": 1006,
            "target": 1007,
            "value": 20            
        },

    ],
    "types": [
                {
                    "type": "school",
                    "image": "image01"
                },
                {
                    "type": "univeristy",
                    "image": "image02"
                },
                {
                    "type": "company",
                    "image": "image03"
                },
            ]   
}
```

I get the list of the type of nodes from `types.type` and append it to a html tag; assigning a color to each list item. When I change the color in the color picker container, in any of the list items, it only changes the color for `d.type == "school"` , because I check manually if the node type `d.type` is equal to **school** and then I apply the `ColorAction` from the last line of the previous function.
how can I change it (`d.type == "school"`) to match the `type` of the node type found in the `nodes.type` of json and accessible in each object of the `mynodes = obj.nodes`?

```
var ColorAction = "";
$(document).ready(function () {
    $.getJSON("databeta.json", function (obj) {
        $('#filterColor').data('types', obj.types.map(function (o) {
            // console.log(o.type);
            return o.type;
        })).append(obj.types.map(function (o) {
            return '<li>' + o.type + '<input class="color-picker" type="text"/></li>';
        }).join(''));

        var data = $('#filterColor').data('types');
        // console.log("end", data);

        mynodes = obj.nodes;
        console.log("mynodes : ", mynodes);

        $("#filterColor .color-picker").each(function(){
            $(this).spectrum({
                color: (function (m, s, c) {
                    return (c ? arguments.callee(m, s, c - 1) : '#') +
                        s[m.floor(m.random() * s.length)]
                })(Math, '0123456789ABCDEF', 5),
                preferredFormat: "rgb",
                showInput: true,
                showPalette: true,
                showAlpha: true,
                palette: [["red", "rgba(0, 255, 0, .5)", "rgb(0, 0, 255)"]],
                change: function(color) {
                    MyNode = d3.select("#node").selectAll(".school").select("circle");
                    MyNode.style("fill", function(d) {
                        return d3.rgb(color.toHexString())
                    });
                    ColorAction = d3.rgb(color.toHexString());
                }
            });
        });

    });
});
```

`ColorAction` which passes into this function to update the color for `d.type == "school"` of the nodes which have type **school**:

```
function ColorType(d)
{
  if (d.type == "school") { return ColorAction;}
}
```

this function applies the color chosen above in the color picker container to the nodes which have the specified type. So the goal is to incorporate this function into each list item above so that each color picker container updates the color of the same type that the list item belongs to.

### update:

i have already a global variable `TypesTab` that stores the `types` of my json, and is accessible inside the `ColorType` function, when i do a console log, it repeats the `types` object of json file the number of times that I have nodes. .

### update2:

for example, instead of hardcoding the **school** type, I can reach it through:

```
if (d.type == TypesTab[0].type) { return ColorAction;}
```

but again, all of the list items behave in the same way, whether I change the color from one color picker of another in list of types, it only changes the color for `TypesTab[0].type` which is school.

### update 3:

here is how I later use the `colortype` function to color the nodes:

```
 node.append("circle")
     .attr("r", 20)
     .attr("y", -25)
     .style("fill", function(d) { return ColorType(d); })
     .style("stroke-width",0.5)
     .style("stroke",'black')
     .attr("opacity", "1");
```

Answer (score 1):

Use for  loop

```
 function ColorType(d){
     for (var i = 0; i < TypesTab.length; i++) {
      if (d.type == TypesTab[i].type) { return ColorAction;}
    }

}
```

Comment: yes, thanks, but this function needs to be connected to/integrated with the `function(color)` above so that each color picker container only colors the node type that it belongs to. how can this be done so?